# Find total sum and sum of numbers in range based on condition

Tags: python, sum, integer, range

I want to create a function `my_sum_div(a, b, div=10)` which will compute the sum of numbers from `a` to `b`, prints out this sum, but also all intermediate sums of type `a+(a+1)+(a+2)+(a+3)` that are divisible by `div`.
I want the program to work as follows:

```
    my_sum_div(1, 10, 2)
```

The output should look like:

```
sums divisible by 2:
6
10
28
36
sum of numbers between 1 and 10 is: 55
```

Now I have already done this:

```
    def my_sum(a, b):
    print("sum of numbers between", a," and", b," is", sum(i for i in 
    range(a, b+1)))

    def my_sum_div(a, b, div = 3):
    print("sums divisible by", div,":")

    l = []
    s = ","
    x = sum(i for i in range(a, b+1)
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        if (i%div==0):
            l.append(str(i))

    print(s.join(l))

    print("sum of numbers between", a, " and", b, " is", sum(i for i in 
    range(a, b + 1))
```

Ive been trying for hours. I know my code only checks what numbers between `(a, b+1)` are divisible by `div`, but how do I make it so that the function computes and prints all the intermediate sums that are divisible by `div`? My first function only computes the sum of all integers in the given interval. I now want the subsequent function to compute all intermediate sums that are divisible by div in a given interval and print all of these.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, there is a common formula just using the value of `b`.  For the sum of all values `1..b` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: Tip: it'd be easier to follow if your code blocks were properly indented -- e.g. is `my_sum_div()` defined *inside* of `my_sum()`? (I think not, but looks that way as is) After indenting four spaces to start a code block, be sure to indent an additional four (or two) on the line after a `def ...`, just as you would when writing python into your editor/IDE. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_sum_div(a,b,div):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(a, b + 1):
            sum += i
            if sum % div == 0:
                print(sum)
        return sum

print(my_sum_div(1,10,2))
```

Output:

```
6
10
28
36
55
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create your custom [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) to [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) the results as:

```
def my_sum_div(start, end, d):
    my_sum = 0
    for x in range(start, end+1):
        my_sum += x 
        if my_sum % d == 0:
            yield my_sum
    # yield my_sum     # <-- uncomment this if you want the total 
                       #     sum to be returned at the end
```

Using above generator, you may yield one result at a time with [**`next()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) as:

```
>>> my_generator = my_sum_div(1, 10, 2)
>>> next(my_generator)
6
>>> next(my_generator)
10
>>> next(my_generator)
28
```

OR you may get the list of all the results in one go as:

```
>>> list(my_sum_div(1, 10, 2))
[6, 10, 28, 36]
```

---

Result with commented version of code to yield total `my_sum` at last:

```
>>> list(my_sum_div(1, 10, 2))
[6, 10, 28, 36, 55]
```

In Python 3, you can simply store the sum of intermediate values and the total sum at the end in two variables as:

```
>>> *intermediate_sum, total_sum = list(my_sum_div(1, 10, 2))
# where: 
#  - `intermediate_sum` will hold the value `[6, 10, 28, 36]`
#  - `total_sum` will hold the value `55`
```

For older versions of Python, you need to do:

```
>>> sum_list = list(my_sum_div(1, 10, 2))
>>> intermediate_sum, total_sum = sum_list[:-1], sum_list[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my implementation

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    return sum(i for i in range(a, b+1)))

def my_sum_div(a, b, div = 3):
    print("sums divisible by", div,":")

    l = []
    s = ","
    test = 0
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        test += i
        if (test%div==0):
            l.append(str(test))

    print(s.join(l))

    print("sum of numbers between", a, " and", b, " is", my_sum(a, b))
```